# New Ubuntu Install, password won't work

Tags: login

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 14.04. Everything seemed to go fine.  However, when I tried to login at the gui prompt, Ubuntu won't let me login, but does not give the red lettering indicated wrong password.  If I try another password, that is obviously wrong, it says wrong password.  I can't get past the login prompt.

I tried the password reset procedure using the advanced prompt, etc at login. I got that to work fine. However, I still can't log in to Ubuntu. When I changed the password, I went to a 8 letter password in case the fact that I had a 5 letter password was the problem.

Next, I tried a terminal prompt by going to cnt alt f1.  I go to the terminal login and it lets me login fine with my username and new password.  However, when I try to toggle to the gui by al, f7, it brings me to the login prompt and will not accept my password again.....I figured it would just jump me to the gui past the login prompt, I guess not.

So what do I do?  I don't get this.  Seems like stuff like this happens most eveytime I install Linux.  Endless problems. Any help would be great.

I just installed mint on a netbook and that was easy.  For Ubuntu, I am leaving windows on this laptop and put ubuntu on a 12gig partition created during the install process.

The only anomaly I can see is that my username should be 'steve' but Ubuntu capitalized that at initial login for me so it is 'Steve'. When I did the terminal login I used 'steve'.

Is this the issue?  Is there way to change the gui username which is autofilled for me each time?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the shell again by pressing CTRL + ALT + F1, log in and create a new user:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

Once created, reboot.

Log in with the newly created user. If it works, go to the "User Accounts" window and delete the old one.

Hope it helps,

Regards

Comment: It was a good idea! I tried it, but it did not work.  Same symptom.  I  created a new user but the screen flashes after entering the PW and it goes back to prompting for a PW. No red wording indicating wrong password (PW).  Very odd.

Comment: Can I just install a new ubuntu?  Maybe use the same partitions and just manually point to them during install?  That was my first thought, but I figured I'd ask here about fixing it. I am not attached to the operating system as I have not used it yet. No data stored, etc.

Comment: I guess that would be the easiest to try, yes.